# Sound waves travel so fast. Hence how can they be considered a quasi static process?

Tags: waves, acoustics

Sound waves travel so fast. We apply the rules of adiabatic process (quasi static) to derive at the equation for speed of sound. My doubt is that how can sound be considered a quasi static process since it travels at high speed?

Comment: The adiabatic assumption for a sound wave is addressed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244079/why-are-sound-waves-adiabatic). See also Fletcher's "[Adiabatic Assumption for Wave Propagation](http://phys.unsw.edu.au/music/people/publications/Fletcher1974a.pdf)" and ["Why are very short times so long and very
long times so short in elastic waves?"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3444.pdf), which are aimed at addressing misconceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Because the wave is going so fast, the little parcels of air that participate in the compression/rarefaction process of sound wave travel have almost no time available in which to exchange compression heat or rarefaction cooling between one another as the wave passes through them. In addition, the absolute magnitude of the pressure differences contained in the wave are very small, making the magnitude of the heating/cooling process tiny. This means the overall process can be considered quasistatic.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer on stack exchange,
[How is sound wave quasistatic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213001/252460)

Comment: Im reproducing the answer given. "We know sound wave is a longitudinal wave and it propagates through compression and rarefaction process. Now this compression or rarefaction process takes place in air layer which is very thin. So the time taken by the process is enough for a quasi-static compression or rarefaction. Yes, the velocity of the sound wave is high but the width of the air layers also very small. That's why time taken for this process is enough. It is naturally quite larger than relaxation time." Question is what is relaxation time?

Comment: What you have mentioned in the ques has been answerd , if you have new ques do write it above , and specify clearly